# Magento Shopping cart empty after adding product to cart and proceed to checkout

Tags: magento, fastcgi, magento-1.9, mod-fcgid

I do have problem while checkout out cart getting empty, strange thing is not for everyone and not always.

In few system it's working fine and most of the system shopping cart empty.i am using FPC a free full page cache module even disabling that no help.

I have tried following things with no luck.

- 1.Set the higher cookies value in session cookie management 1day,10day,100day,cookie domain set to blank and path set to (/ and
  or blank)
     Use HTTP Only to No

  and in session validation setting everything set to NO (Validate REMOTE_ADDR,Validate HTTP_VIA,Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,Validate
  HTTP_USER_AGENT,Use SID on Frontend)

  When  HTTP_USER_AGENT set to Yes, new error came the page has a redirect loop but clearing the cookies and cahe working but not the
  solution.

  When (Validate REMOTE_ADDR,Validate HTTP_VIA,Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,Use SID on Frontend) any of these set to Yes
  page started redirecting to home page, not able to see product page.
  But no luck
- 2.commented the code in Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start() 
     $cookieParams = array(
                 'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
                 'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
                 /*'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
                 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
                 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()*/
             );
     No Luck
- 3.Strange thing happened always i am getting two different cookie with same name as frontend with different domain values domain.com
  and .domain.com with sometimes different value for chrome and firefox
  one (domain.com). I am failing to understand who is setting this
  cookie domain in magento when commented out the above code still has
  the cookie domain and even when domain explicitly set to blank still
  there is cookie domain. i manually searched those cookie values in
  var/session folder and found those entries as well.

  Does anyone have any further idea how to get rid of this.

Comment: Do you always access the website from the same subdomain? It may differ if you access from www. or non-www. 
Maybe you are setting cookies (via ajax?) for cart on www. and running the website on non-www!

Comment: see this post as i am currently testing it to see if it helps http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57890/shopping-cart-shows-as-empty-upon-clicking-add-to-cart